# Group row by item in ArrayType column using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Pyspark DataFrame with Schema like this

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Example:

```
id        address        phone_list
1         HaNoi          [ 012346789, 032145698, 0565622253 ]
2         Singapore      [ 012346789, 069855633 ]
3         Moscow         [ 023466466, 069855633 ]
4         Tokyo          [ 044656611, 061316561 ]
```

You can see that id 1 have 1 phone number in common with id 2 (012346789), and id 2 have 1 phone number in common with id 3 (069855633), so i want to create new dataframe to group these ids together.
It looks like:

```
id  address                               phone_list
1   [ HaNoi , Singapore, Moscow ]         [ 012346789, 032145698, 0565622253, 069855633, 023466466 ]
2   [ Tokyo ]                            [ 044656611, 061316561 ]
```

Anyone has the hint or solution?

Comment: You will probably need `explode`, `groupBy` and `collect_list`. And also create a separate category column that indicates the final groupings you need. It may be easier to create this category column using UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in your case is

```
df= pyspark.sql('''select id, address, phone_number 
from table_name as tb  LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(tb.phone_list)as phone_number ''')
```

to explode the list, and then I would group by phone_number!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first explode the phone numbers, then do a group by on phone numbers and do a collect list of addresses. Also, you need to collect_set on phone numbers (collect_set() contains distinct elements and collect_list() contains all elements) to get distinct set of phone numbers. Let me know if you want the complete code.